# R is returning an ID that is not in the data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with several variables that represent ID numbers (the data frames in the workspace are all originally tables from a normalized database). I was surprised to see that I am sometimes able to reference an ID's description before I use the merge to map the description in, but only if I use the $ notation. For example: I set up data frame q to include the variable "LocationID". Then I do the following...

Example for 1 & 2:

```
> colnames(q)
[1] "LocationID" "PlanID"     "Rate"      

> sort(unique(q[,'Location')) #This fails. duh
Error in `[.data.frame`(q, , "Location") : undefined columns selected

> sort(unique(q$Location)) #This works. what?
[1]  1  2  3
```

Questions

1. Why does the second one work? Maybe that's looking a gift horse in the mouth.
2. Why doesn't the first one work if the first one does?
3. For the above example, q is constructed from another data frame with more
   variables. This fails for the larger data frame. Why does it fail?

Example for 3:

```
> dim(y)
[1] 207171     86

q<-y[,cbind('LocationID','PlanID','Rate')]

> dim(q)
[1] 207171      3

> unique(y$Location)
NULL

> unique(q$Location)
[1]  1  2  3
```

Comment: The `$` operator supports partial matching.

Comment: Current versions of R should issue a warning when partial matching occurs.

Comment: @jdharrison is correct, and you can read more about this in the help for `?\`[\``

Comment: That makes sense. @jdharrison: want to submit that as an answer so I can give credit where credit is due?